# How to verify if a WebElement(Button,Dropdown) is enabled Using TestNG?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a dropdown and a button on a web page.please suggest how to verify if a WebElement(Button,Dropdown) is enabled Using TestNG framework?

one more thing when we work on TestNG we have to use assert in order to get the status of the test case. so if i want to know whether button is enabled.can i use assert here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Button

```
   elem = driver.find_element_by_id("myId")
if elem.is_enabled():
    elem.click()
else:
    pass # whatever logic to handle...
```

For DropDown

```
 Boolean dropdownPresent = driver.findElement("YOUR LOCATOR OF DROPDOWN").isDisplayed();

        if(dropdownPresent==true)
        {
            System.out.println("Dropdown is appearing");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Dropdown is not appearing");
        }
```

WebDriver has a W3C specification that details out the information about the different visibility preferences based out on the types of the web elements.

`isDisplayed()` is the method used to verify presence of a web element within the webpage. The method returns a “true” value if the specified web element is present on the web page and a “false” value if the web element is not present on the web page.

`isDisplayed()` is capable to check for the presence of all kinds of web elements available.

`isEnabled()` is the method used to verify if the web element is enabled or disabled within the webpage.

`isEnabled()` is primarily used with buttons.

`isSelected()` is the method used to verify if the web element is selected or not.

`isSelected()` method is pre-dominantly used with radio buttons, drop downs and checkboxes.

for more understanding check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156656/how-to-verify-element-present-or-visible-in-selenium-2-selenium-webdriver

Hope it helps
Thanks

Comment: @log_file: Thanks a lot. one more thing when we work on TestNG we have to use assert in order to get the status of the test case. so if i want to know whether button is enabled.can i use assert here?